# I am working on Media Capture module in Ionic. How do I design Custom Video Recorder in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, video-capture, ionic-native, mediacapture

I am working on Media Capture module in Ionic. How do I design a Custom Video Recorder in Ionic? I am working in Ionic 5.2.8 (Latest) version. I am planning to build a video recorder in Ionic and came across this matter.

Comment: Can you Elaborate more? What design you are talking about?

Comment: I want to design Instagram like story recorder in ionic.

Comment: Check this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview
this plugin provides you full screen camera with other HTML over screen. your can make it look like Instagram.

Comment: also Check this tutorial: https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-go-create-a-pokemon-go-style-interface-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Does this help record a video clip?